# Magento installation: Getting Fatal error

Tags: magento2, installation, permissions

**I am facing a issue while trying to install magento.
I am getting the following errors. Plz can any one help me...!**

**OS: Ubuntu 16.0.4

apache: 2.4.18

php: 7.0.8

mariaDB: 10.1.16**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: The file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/.regenerate" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/.regenerate): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(173): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php(98): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->delete('/var/.regenerat...')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(114): Magento\Framework\Code\GeneratedFiles->cleanGeneratedFiles() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(385): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(362): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap- in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 382
```

Comment: Please check the permission: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 12):

Your `var` folder does not have the right permissions.

I suggest you follow the official documentation to set the right permissions on your Magento instance: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

> ```
> cd <your Magento install dir>
> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
> find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
> chmod u+x bin/magento
> ```

Comment: @venky07 that's pretty much because your server user is different from the ownership of your files I reckon

Comment: Then how can i resolve that one...!

Comment: @venky07 give a try to umask: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You can easily solve this by going to the document root via terminal and providing permission to var folder like this:

> ```
> chmod -R 777 var
> ```

Then please trying refreshing and the installation mode will be shown for sure.

Comment: Isn't this unsafe?

Comment: no probm, magento 2 demands it.

Comment: For anyone coming here, please do not run this command, especially on a production environment. The accepted answer works just fine.

Comment: Questioner didnt mentioned about whether its in prod or dev.

Comment: also please see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html see what all folders need to be writable in dev mode. hope this helps.

Comment: Anyone help me how to give permission in wamp windows?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is facing the same permission issues (i.e. `/var/.regenerate` Can't be deleted, in the httpd logs)

And none of the below works:

1. `chmod -R 777 var`
2. server user match the ownership of your files
3. `open_basedir` is disabled or correctly set in `php.ini`

Try to check if your Centos 7 installation has SELinux installed:  `sestatus`

If it is, disable it: `setenforce 0`

Comment: Although not ideal, `setenforce 0` did the trick for me. I would stay away from setting 777 on any file.

Comment: absolutely agree. it might be handy during the initial setup, and if with 777 set you still get permission errors than it's definitely something else.
Also,  `setenforce 0` temporarily disables SELinux. You'd need to edit 
 `/etc/selinux/config` in order to disable it permanently or to set the right policy.

Answer (score 0):

I face almost same problem. Instead of searching randomly on internet randomly, go on log file of apache2, in my case my log file located on

/var/apache2/log

then you will found exact problem there.

for my case i found the following error.

> [Sat Nov 10 15:48:36.673289 2018] [:error] [pid 2153] [client
>   127.0.0.1:40744] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can’t create directory
>   /var/www/html/M2/MN226/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.\nClass
>   Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy generation error:
>   The requested class did not generate properly, because the ‘generated’
>   directory permission is read-only. If — after running the ‘bin/magento
>   setup:di:compile’ CLI command when the ‘generated’ directory
>   permission is set to write — the requested class did not generate
>   properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. in
>   /var/www/html/M2/MN226/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/M2/MN226/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass(‘Magento\\Framewo…’)\n#1
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load(‘Magento\\Framewo…’)\n#2
>   [internal function]: spl_autoload_call(‘Magento\\Framewo…’)\n#3
>   /var/www/html/M2/MN226/vendor in
>   /var/www/html/M2/MN226/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on
>   line 135, referer: http://localhost/M2/

my installation directory is var/www/html/M2/MN226/

> Then on that directory you can found a folder call generated.
>
> check the permission of that if not given 777
>
> then give that 777
>
> then everything work correct.then

[image]

Note : i just share my experience, it can help you or not, as everyone situation may not be same. If it's work then okay, If no then ignore it.
I white it on :

https://forum.equaltrue.com/topics/showing-blank-page-while-installing-magento-2-2-6/

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Raphael at Digital Pianism was not solving it for me, I had to execute this command which are three commands chained together:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chmod g+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be another solution.
If you had run:

`$ chmod -R 777 var pub generated`

and nothing was happen (still 500 error on website access)

Then, **restart the container** (docker has a button for that).
Enjoy!